# Difference between using a に particle with a noun

Tags: particles

What's the difference in these 2 sentences?

禁止します

禁止にします

Answer (score 3, accepted):

禁止にします sounds like you will *start* to prohibit something, or you *decided* to prohibit something. This type of に is used in other set phrases related to making a decision (～に決める, ～に決定する). If something has been prohibited for a long time and it is going to be prohibited also in the future, then you have to say 禁止します. If you explicitly want to say you prohibit something *from now on*, 禁止します works but 禁止にします would be more natural.

- タバコは禁止します。
  Smoking is prohibited. / We will prohibit smoking.
- タバコは禁止にします。
  We will prohibit smoking. / We decided to prohibit smoking.